# Solve the functional equation $f(1+xf(y))=yf(x+y)$

Tags: functional-equations

#### Problem

Find all functions   $f:\mathbb{R^+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^+}$ such that:
$$f(1+xf(y))=yf(x+y)$$
for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R^+}$

#### Progress

I can only prove $f$  is a surjective function.  I tried to prove $f$  is   an injective function, but I can't. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people are much more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Also, many would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Find..."), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Comment: Also, does $\mathbb{R}^+$ denote the set of positive reals or the set of nonnegative reals?

Comment: I simply cannot upvote this question because you have been here long enough to know that you should give context and show your work.

Comment: I don't understand the high amount of downvotes! Surely this post is on a non-standard functional equation. Is MSE a wrong forum to pose interesting questions?

Haruboy15's questions are generally very challenging. I doubt that they are 'homework' questions [On the other hand, if it is homework, I would have loved to study at such a school].

Comment: @Isomorphism I understand the downvotes, this is more like an assignment then asking for a helping hand. Also, as Zev said, no own thoughts are given.

Comment: @Isomorphism thanks you, I am preparing to attend the Mathematics contest, so my home work is rather hard, why people always downvote the hard question, I get stuck with this, I can't do anything with this . I only prove $ f(x) $ is a surjective function but I tried to prove $f(x)$ is is an injective function, but I can't .Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Can you put your proof of the surjectivity of $f(x)$ in the OP? It would help with the downvoting problem if you showed some work, especially if you have partially solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Let $y=1$. Then $f(1+xf(1))=f(1+x)$, so either $f(1)=1$, or $f(1+e^x)$ is periodic (this part is explained in more detail later). Let's assume the first to start. If $f$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ (this constraint is relaxed later), then we can let $x\to0$ so that we get $f(1)=yf(y)=1$ whence $f(x)=1/x$. Checking this solution, we get
  $$f(1+xf(y))=yf(y+x)\Rightarrow \frac1{1+x/y}=\frac y{y+x},$$
  which is true, so $f(x)=1/x$ is a solution.
- If we fix some $y\ne1$ such that $f(y)\ne1$ (which exists, because $f(x)=1$ is not a solution) and choose $x$ so that $1+xf(y)=y+x$, then
  $$x=\frac{y-1}{f(y)-1}\Rightarrow f\Big(\!\frac{yf(y)-1}{f(y)-1}\!\Big)=yf\Big(\!\frac{yf(y)-1}{f(y)-1}\!\Big)\Rightarrow f\Big(\!\frac{yf(y)-1}{f(y)-1}\!\Big)=0\notin\mathbb R^+,$$
  which is a contradiction, so either $x=\frac{y-1}{f(y)-1}\le0$ or $y+x=\frac{yf(y)-1}{f(y)-1}\le0$. The second condition implies the first, which is equivalent to
  $$f(y)\ge1\mbox{ if }y\le1\mbox{ and }f(y)\le1\mbox{ if }y\ge1.$$
- If we suppose $a:=\max(f(1),f(1)^{-1})\ne1$, then $f(1+ax)=f(1+x)$ (setting $y=1$). Moreover, this generalizes to
  $$yf(x+y)=f(1+xf(y))=f(1+axf(y))=yf(ax+y)\Rightarrow f(y+x)=f(y+ax),$$
  so letting $y=1-x$, we get $a=f((a-1)x+1)$, so $f(x)=f(1)$ on $[1,a)$ (assuming $a>1$), and by $f(1+ax)=f(1+x)$, it is also constant on $[1,a^2)$, $[1,a^3)$, etc. so that (by induction) it is constant for all $x\ge1$. But then, choosing $y=2$, $f(1+xf(2))=2f(x+2)\Rightarrow$ $f(1)=2f(1)$, since both arguments are greater than $1$, and this is a contradiction. Thus, $f(1)=1$.
- If we assume $f$ is continuous at $1$, then if we let $x\to0$,
  $$\lim_{x\to0}f(y+x)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(1+xf(y))}y=\frac{f(1)}y=\frac1y$$
  which implies that $f$ is continuous almost everywhere (discontinuous on a nowhere-dense set) and equals $1/x$ where it is continuous. For the remaining points, let $x$ be small enough that $f(1+xf(y))=\frac1{1+xf(y)}$ and $f(y+x)=\frac1{y+x}$. Then $\frac1{1+xf(y)}=\frac y{y+x}$ so that $f(y)=1/y$ on $(0,\infty)$.

In summary: $f(x)=1/x$ is a solution, and $\operatorname{sgn}(y-1)=\operatorname{sgn}(1-f(y))$. Other than that, it is known that any other solution will have to be discontinuous at $1$.
More work to be done, I think...

Answer (score 1):

Set $x=0$. We then get that
$$f(1) = y f(y) \implies f(y) = \dfrac{f(1)}y$$
Hence, we have
$$\dfrac{f(1)}{1+xf(y)} = \dfrac{yf(1)}{x+y} \implies 1 + xf(y) = 1 + \dfrac{x}y \implies f(y) = \dfrac1{y} \implies f(1) = 1$$
Hence, we get that
$$f(x) = \dfrac1x$$

Comment: I think you can't set $x=0$ here because it says that for all $ x;y \in \mathbb{R^+}$

Comment: @Haruboy15 That depends on your convention for the definition of $\mathbb{R}^+$

Comment: If you allow $0$ for $x$, you must also allow it for $y$.  But with $x=y=0$, you get $f(1) = 0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Provided $f(0)$ is defined.

Comment: @Haruboy15 I only saw that the domain and range are in $\mathbb{R}^+$. If $x,y \neq 0$, then if you assume continuity of $f$ then again it gives you $1/x$ as a solution.